# Keyboard rebuilds the build method in flutter

Tags: flutter, controller, textfield

I have a scenario in which I'm getting data from **firebase using Futurebuilder** and creating TextFields using these data that's **create a list of TextFields** with their unique controllers.
When I click on any TextField and **as keyboard opens/close it call the build method again** that's I'm unable to update the text.
How can i resolve it?
I have tried `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` but it didn't work.

```
// Outside the build method
Map<String, TextEditingController> _controllers = {};


FutureBuilder<List<PlaceholderModel>>(
            future: userService.getOwnPlaceholderData(),
            builder: (context,snapshot){
              if (snapshot.hasData) {

              for (int index = 0; index < snapshot.data!.length; index++) {
                  final controller = TextEditingController(text: snapshot.data?[index].title);
                  controller.text = snapshot.data?[index].placeholder ?? '';
                  _controllers[snapshot.data?[index].title ?? ''] = controller;

                }
                return Listview.builder();
              }

              ...
              });
```

Comment: Kindly add some code please